# tkinter cannot get attribute from self

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an error that it cannot get the attribute self.story1 , self.story2...
but self.window object does not call an error. why is it showing me an error?

```
from tkinter import *

class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.window = master
        self.__setwindow__()

        "schedule list"
        self.story1 = [""]
        self.story2 = [""]
        self.story3 = [""]
        self.story4 = [""]

    def __setwindow__(self):
        self.window.geometry("300x500")

        self.title = Label(text="오늘 할일을 작성하시오.")
        self.title.place(x=80, y=30)

        for a,b,c,d in [len(i) for i in [self.story1, self.story2, self.story3, self.story4]]:
            print(a,b,c,d)

ob = Tk()
Main(master = ob)
ob.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have called `self.__setwindow__()` before creating those story variables.

Comment: First of all, call ```self.__setwindow__()``` at the bottom, i.e after```self.story4```. Also, why are you trying to fetch from an integer? This line: ```for a,b,c,d in [len(i) for i in [self.story1, self.story2, self.story3, self.story4]]:``` will give an error. Perhaps you mean: ```for a,b,c,d in [i for i in zip(self.story1, self.story2, self.story3, self.story4)]:```